# Flicker on data update Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flicker

I have a collection of users which needs to be updated incase the data is changed in the database. For this I am calling the update function from the controller.

**In Controller**

```
$scope.update = function(){
    $http.get("....")
    .success(function(data){
        $scope.users = data;
    })
};
```

**In Template**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
  ...
</div>
```

Div flicker can be noticed on update function call. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean by 'flicker'? Does it occur initially, when the page loads the first time, or every time you call the update method?

Comment: Use [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations)?

Comment: @JanS everytime I call the update function

Comment: I don't know how big your data sets are and if performance is key, but you could try diffing your current and new data - removing those that are not present anymore and adding the new ones.

Comment: I thought about comparing the old and new data but that would mean more coding. May be someone out there has a better solution.

Comment: How often do you call the update method? If it's mostly an issue when displaying the same data, you could just avoid setting $scope.users when $scope.users and data are equal

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Was looking for some solution other than mine. Probably this is the only one.

Root cause of the 'flickering' is recreating DOM because you assign new, plain object to the scope: `$scope.users = data;`. The object doesn't contain Angular's tracking data, so the engine initiates everything from the beginning. The effect is annoying especially when you use CSS animations on elements being refreshed - everything is blinking, resetting, etc.

What I do to avoid it? I don't do `$scope.data = data;`, but I do update every single object of `$scope.data` by its new version from `data` (in your case).

Check out the code below. In my case, I fetch fresh list of servers, then I apply only changes.

```
$scope.servers = [];

$http.get('/panel/dashboard').then(function(res) {
    // find and upgrade servers
    for (var n in res.data.servers) {
        var s = res.data.servers[n];

        var l = get_server(s.id); // helper - get by ID from $scope.servers
        if (l) {
            $scope.servers.push({
                id: s.id, 
                name: s.name, 
                state: s.state
            });
        } else {
            // do update values only
            l.name = s.name;
            l.state = s.state;                
        }
    }

    // remember to remove old items that are in $scope.server and not in res.data
    // then sort data   
});
```

I hope it helps. The most important thing here is not 'how to solve' but understand 'how it works'.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution, it works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `ng-cloak` directive to your  tag along with the following CSS:

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

More information can be found at Angular documentation -- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak.

The documents states that the CSS is embedded in the `angular.js` file...but since I usually, as per best practices, load my JavaScript *at the end* of the page, the flicker still happens. Instead I just add the necessary CSS to my sites css file and that seems to work.

Comment: I tried this but am not able to get it to work. I read somewhere that this work only for first page load.